# MongoDB repair failed due to Invariant failure rs.get() src/mongo/db/catalog/database.cpp

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB Version: 3.4.24
MongoDB hosted on Linux server was abruptly shut down due to the over-utilization of memory.
Initiated the mongodb repair using: `sudo mongod  -f /etc/mongodrepair.conf --repair`
The whole database is of 2.5TB, while repairing/re-indexing the db, close to 2.4TB was successfully repaired but the last 972MB of DB repair was failed due to Invariantfailure error.

**Repair Logs**

```
2020-07-04T17:17:07.441+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]          building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 50 megabytes of RA$  
2020-07-04T17:17:07.448+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: test.summary properties: { v: 1, key: { totalVolume: -1 }, name: "totalV$
lume_-1", ns: "test.summary", background: true }
2020-07-04T17:17:07.448+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]          building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 50 megabytes of RA$  
2020-07-04T17:17:07.456+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: test.summary properties: { v: 1, key: { ts: -1 }, name: "ts_-1", ns: "test.summary", background: true }  
2020-07-04T17:17:07.456+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]          building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 50 megabytes of RA$  
2020-07-04T17:17:08.673+0000 I -        [initandlisten]  Invariant failure rs.get() src/mongo/db/catalog/database.cpp 195    
2020-07-04T17:17:08.673+0000 I -        [initandlisten]   
  
***aborting after invariant() failure  
  
  
2020-07-04T17:17:08.717+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

**Restart Logs**

```
2020-07-04T17:39:14.476+0000 I CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=20485 port=27017 dbpath=/home/db324 64-bit host=ip-*-*-*-*  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.24  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "-.-.-.-", port: 27017 }, replication: $  
 oplogSizeMB: 10240, replSetName: "rs1" }, storage: { dbPath: "/home/db324", directoryPerDB: true, engine: "wiredTiger", journal: { enabled$
 true }, wiredTiger: { engineConfig: { cacheSizeGB: 108.0 } } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.lo$
" } }  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.480+0000 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /home/db324/mongod.lock is not empty.  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.499+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.499+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]   
2020-07-04T17:39:14.499+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: The configured WiredTiger cache size is more than 80% of available RAM.  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.499+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=110592M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,t$
reads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000)$
checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.667+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593884354:667272][20485:0x7fdbcb287580], txn-recover: Main recovery loop$
 starting at 73368/128  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.667+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593884354:667951][20485:0x7fdbcb287580], txn-recover: Recovering log 733$
8 through 73369  
2020-07-04T17:39:14.733+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1593884354:733044][20485:0x7fdbcb287580], txn-recover: Recovering log 733$
9 through 73369  
2020-07-04T17:39:15.164+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31802) [1593884355:164908][20485:0x7fdbcb287580], test/collectio$
-56-3854974571131417844.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: /home/db324/test/collection-56-3854974571131417844.wt: handle-read: pread: failed $
to read 4096 bytes at offset 28672: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error  
2020-07-04T17:39:15.164+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError: -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredT$
ger error at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp 113  
2020-07-04T17:39:15.165+0000 I -        [initandlisten]   
  
***aborting after invariant() failure
```

Is there a way to repair/recover the last part of the DB? or
Is there a way to ignore the broken DB? or
Is it possible to cut out the whole 2.4TB data sans the last error db and create a new MongoDB instance with 2.4TB?

I would greatly appreciate the help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The repair log indicates that it failed building an index on `ns: "test.summary"`,

The other log gives you the file name, and the offset of the error:

> /home/db324/test/collection-56-3854974571131417844.wt: handle-read: pread: failed $
> to read 4096 bytes at offset 28672

The data after that point in the file is likely unsalvageable.  You might try:

1. Make a backup of the existing files
2. Remove the file /home/db324/test/collection-56-3854974571131417844.wt
3. Re-run mongod --repair on this dbpath

If all goes well, it will create a new, empty file for that collection.

If you need to try to salvage that data, after the above succeeds so that you know the rest of the data files are consistent, recopy that file from the backup and attempt repair again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Joe. 
After removing the file /home/db324/test/collection-56-3854974571131417844.wt, i re-ran the mongod --repair which resulted in a "Segmentation Fault" error. Not sure what next to do.